# Add a user along with one custom post type

Tags: wordpress

I am developing this plugin that admin can add a user in the backend and when user is created, plugin can automatically generate one custom post which I have added to the theme. The custom post will store user ID that is just created (or if it is possible make that user an author of the post)

I wonder if what I have mentioned above is possible practically. If anybody has any better advice, I am open for any suggestions.

Thank you in advance

Comment: why you want to create a custom post type with `user_id`?

Comment: it is going to be some sort of membership-base website that allows users to write their own stories but once the user is created they will have one custom post (story) automatically created and listed in their dashboard (which I have created in front end) as an example story. This means, every user that get registered by admin will have one story (Custom post type) added their account automatically. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that a unique custom post type per user is the best way to implement what you're wanting to achieve. If you have 100 users, you will have 100 custom post types making the wp-admin a nightmare as the left menu would grow with so many menu-items.

Wouldn't it be easier to just use a normal post type and then have the page that shows the user's dashboard filter the posts to only show posts where the user is the post_author? You could then add a hook to catch when a user registers and create the example post, you could modify the code below and add it to your functions.php:

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save', 10, 1 );

function myplugin_registration_save( $user_id ) {

        $userPostsCategory = 3;

        // Create post object
        $my_post = array(
          'post_title'    => 'Sample Story' ),
          'post_content'  => 'You can edit this or create a new story',
          'post_status'   => 'publish',
          'post_author'   => user_id,
          'post_category' => array( $userPostsCategory )
        );

        // Insert the post into the database
        wp_insert_post( $my_post );

}
```

This method will lower the number of customisations you'd have to do to your themes and make management of the posts a little easier.

Further reading on this:

- [User registration hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register)
- [Inserting a post using wp_insert_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/)